# add column age from column birthdate in R

Tags: r, dataframe, multiple-columns

| Name | Date |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1990-10-7 |
| B | 1997-11-20 |

and i want to add column age the convert the date to the age

i try this

```
data$age <- age_calc(as.Date(data$dob, "%Y/%m/%d"), units = "years")
```

but i got this error

```
Error in if (any(enddate < dob)) { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

Comment: Hello Ahmed, Is your column named "dob" or "Date"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is in the format you are giving to `as.Date` function

```
> df$age <- age_calc(as.Date(df$Date, "%Y-%m-%d"), units = "years")
> df
  Name       Date      age
1    A  1990-10-7 32.15342
2    B 1997-11-20 25.03288
```

Note that your `Date` variable use `-` as separator instead of `/` so you have to use `-` inside `as.Date`

Answer (score 0):

I recommend installing and calling the lubridate package.

Then:

data$age <- trunc((data$Date %--% today()) / years(1))